# ¿Como Realizar condiciones de busqueda?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, web

Soy nuevo en **`PHP`** y realizando un formulario buscador que devuelve datos según las opciones que elija el usuario, tengo Tipo y Fecha desde a una fecha determinada pero no logro hacer que filtre solo por fecha en caso de que el usuario no elija el tipo.

```
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $fecha1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
    $fecha2 = $_POST['fecha2'];

    ///FILTROS

    if (isset($_POST['filtrar'])){

        if ($status === "Todos"){ 

         $where = "WHERE TR_APOYOS.FECHA_REGISTRO BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '.$fecha2.' ";;

        } else if(!($_POST[$status])){
          $Where = "WHERE TC_ESTATUS_APOYOS.NOMBRE LIKE '".$status."%'";;

        }else if(!($_POST[$fecha1])){
          $Where = "WHERE TC_ESTATUS_APOYOS.NOMBRE LIKE '".$status."%' OR TR_APOYOS.FECHA_REGISTRO BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '.$fecha2.' ";;

        }

    } 
    // end FILTROS

?>
```

Comment: creo que tienes un error en `} else if(!($_POST[$status])){`, deberia ser `} else if(!($_POST['status'])){` entre comillas y sin el $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer estas accediendo mal a `$_POST["status"]` y te faltan comillas en `fecha2` ademas creo que el primer filtro esta de mas. trata de verificar si tus datos llegan para evitar y tener control sobre los errores

Ejemplo:

```
$status = (isset($_POST['status']))?$_POST['status']:"";
$fecha1 = (isset($_POST['fecha1']))?$_POST['fecha1']:"";
$fecha2 = (isset($_POST['fecha2']))?$_POST['fecha2']:"";
    ///FILTROS
    if (isset($_POST['filtrar'])){
        //if ($status === "Todos"){ 
        // $where = "WHERE TR_APOYOS.FECHA_REGISTRO BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."'";
        //} else 
        if($status){
          $Where = "WHERE TC_ESTATUS_APOYOS.NOMBRE LIKE '".$status."%'";
        }else if($fecha1&&$fecha2){
          $Where = "WHERE  TR_APOYOS.FECHA_REGISTRO BETWEEN '".$fecha1."' AND '".$fecha2."'";
        }
    } 
    // end FILTROS
?>
```